# In PHP, is there a way to display human-readable information about a variable in error_log()?

Tags: php, debugging, error-logging

I want to do something like:

```
error_log('this is information about the variable: '.print_r($variable));
```

or

```
error_log('this is information about the variable: '.var_dump($variable));
```

FYI, the variable I'm trying to print is an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) accepts a second parameter which will return its output as a string. As such, your first example can be modified to the following:

```
error_log('this is information about the variable: ' . print_r($variable, true));
```

**Note:** While `var_dump()` does not have such a parameter, you could use output buffering to store its output as described [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
error_log(
    'this is information about the variable: '.print_r($variable, true), 
    3, 
    "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

More info: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php